# Error when updating Bootstrap 7.30 to 7.35

Tags: 7, theming

Im getting the following error when visting the root of my Drupal 7 project after updating the sites bootstrap theme from 7.30 to 7.35.

```
Notice: Undefined index: element in bootstrap_menu_link() (line 22 of /Users/Chris/Sites/iss-mw/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/menu/menu-link.func.php).
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to l() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Users/Chris/Sites/iss-mw/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/menu/menu-link.func.php on line 52 and defined in l() (line 2481 of /Users/Chris/Sites/iss-mw/includes/common.inc).
```

Seems to be some issue with the menu-link.func. Anyone know what this could be?

Cheers!

Comment: Two questions: have you cleared menu cache? If you log the menu items that are giving the errors, are all menu items giving this or just some, especially those that are not suppose to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

This is probabbly not related to bootstrap theme itself, because the function `bootstrap_menu_link()` is the same in both versions.
As I can see the error is because the `element` key is empty

```
22. $element = $variables['element']
```

So, when the the function try to call the `l()` function, throw an error fatal, because is expecting an array as 3rd argument

```
52. $element['#title'] = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
```